# Best way to concatenate an array prefix and an array reversed prefix

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given two arrays and two indices, I need to concatenate the prefix of the first array and the reversed prefix of the second array.

For example:

```
// Input
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15];
ind1 = 6;
ind2 = 3;

// Output
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,12,11,10];
```

Here is my code:

```
function Concat(arr1,arr2,ind1,ind2) {
    let arr = [];
    for (let n = 0; n < ind1; n++)
        arr.push(arr1[n]);
    for (let n = ind2; n > 0; n--)
        arr.push(arr2[n-1]);
    return arr;
}
```

I am looking for a better (cleaner / faster / simpler / more elegant) way to do this. What can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**Note:** This will not be faster than current approach. This is just little cleaner.

```js
function Concat(arr1,arr2,ind1,ind2) {
  return [].concat(arr1.slice(0, ind1), arr2.slice(0, ind2).reverse());
}

arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15];
ind1 = 6;
ind2 = 3;

console.log(Concat(arr1, arr2, ind1, ind2))
```

---

As suggested, there will not be huge performance impact. You can check the difference **[js-perf sample](https://jsperf.com/for-vs-array-concat)**.

---

An alternate approach if you have ability to override input structure.

Since we are expecting array of object in custom order, it will be easy to make it generic. Assuming the structure to be:

<sub>*Please mind the syntax as I'm heavily working on Typescript, it is easier for me to write in that syntax.*</sub>

```js
interface ConcatObject {
  value: Array<any>;
  endIndex: number;
  isReverse: boolean
}
```

when you read, it makes code easier to read and simpler to make it generic.

```js
function Concat(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    var temp = cur.value.slice(0, cur.endIndex);
    if (cur.isReverse) {
      temp = temp.reverse();
    }
    return acc.concat(temp);
  }, []);
}

var data = [{
    value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    endIndex: 6
  },
  {
    value: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    endIndex: 3,
    isReverse: true
  }
]

console.log(Concat(data))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!! Would that be significantly less efficient, maybe due to creation of "too many" temporary arrays?

Comment: No. If you have big arrays like 1M items, it will be evident. I'll try to create a performance difference and update in answer

Comment: @goodvibration I have added a performance comparison. You can check it.

Comment: With regards to your first solution - would `arr1.slice(0, ind1).concat(arr2.slice(0, ind2).reverse())` be equal or better in terms of performance? Because in terms of "elegance" it is slightly better (though it's a subjective matter of opinion I suppose).

Comment: @goodvibration I dont think it would be any difference. Having an inline array will not have any impact. You can (if you have a git account) edit jsperf post to test on your own. But micro optimizations are never worth the effort. Rather try to make your code more readable. That said, if you have huge arrays, and if performance is what matters, I'd go with your solution. If not, I'll stick to mine as there is not much impact

Answer (score 2):

If ES6 is not a problem, you can do it by the code below:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var arr2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15];
var ind1 = 6;
var ind2 = 3;
var output = [...arr1.slice(0, ind1), ...arr2.slice(0, ind2).reverse()];
console.log(output);
```

If you don't want to use ES6 spread syntax, you can use *array.prototype.concat* :

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var arr2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15];
var ind1 = 6;
var ind2 = 3;
var output = arr1.slice(0, ind1).concat(arr2.slice(0, ind2).reverse());
console.log(output);
```

Comment: The code is server side, so browsers are not an issue. Thank you.

Comment: What do those `...` mean though?

Comment: It's called spread syntax: it just converts [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: No offense but your second snippet is very similar to my answer. For some users, this may make my answer void. Also lets try to avoid duplication of content.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution

**Code:**

```
// declarations
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15];
ind1 = 6;
ind2 = 3;
var arr = [];

// changing length as per index
arr1.length = ind1;
arr2.length = ind2;

// reverse and concat to array
arr = arr1.concat(arr2.reverse());
console.log(arr);
```

Clean, Fast and efficient.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Except for the fact that you change the input arrays (in my specific case I don't care much about it, but in the general case you might impose undesired subsequent results).

Comment: That part was not mentioned in the question. The above solution is based on the question asked.

Comment: Since arrays in javascript are passed by reference, I think it makes more sense that unless otherwise mentioned, one should not change this type of input inside the function (which will change also outside the function). A matter of opinion I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concat many arrays you can look at this solution. This lets you to `concat` how many arrays you want and in which order using `function cascading`. You can continue this cascading and use `optional parameter` for `reverse` order.

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
const arr2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15];

const obj = {
  items: [],
  concat(arr, index, isReverse = false) {
     let temp = arr.slice(0, index);
     this.items = this.items.concat(isReverse ? temp.reverse() : temp);
     return this;
  }
};

obj.concat(arr1, 6).concat(arr2, 3, true);
console.log(obj.items);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how more elegant to what I already have, this solution is...

Comment: This lets you to bind how many arrays you want. Your solution lets you only 2 arrays.

Comment: OK, but I only need two array - the prefix of the first one, and the reversed prefix of the second one.

Comment: I just give you a general solution. Maybe another can use this in it's case :). Maybe you later

Answer (score 1):

Using es6

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    arr2 = [10,11,12,13,14,15];
let ind1 = 6,
    ind2 = 3;

let newArr = [...arr1.slice(0, ind1), ...arr2.slice(0, ind2).reverse()];

console.log(newArr)
```